# nodejs & mongoose - check on unfetched fields

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, database

A lot of my validation functions rely on comparing the values of `model.some_field`.  However, if I launch a query like:

```
model.find({ _id: 'someid' }, 'field1 field2 field3', function(err, doc) {
  doc.someMethod();
});
```

and someMethod looks like:

```
modelSchema.methods.someMethod = function() {
  if(!this.field4) return false;
  (...)
}
```

Then could I expect someMethod to fail?  Is there a performance friendly way to check for field4?  The only method I can think of is something like

```
this.modal('model').findById(this._id, function(){ [check the value on callback here] }
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: You're selecting (http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.find) 3 fields, `field1`, `field2`, `field3`, and then wondering if `field4` would be present? I don't understand.

Comment: @WiredPrairie, so field4 is obv not going to be present since it isn't fetched, yet a lot of my validation depends on the value of field4.  Would I have to refetch it in a different query - or is there a best practice that eliminates this need?

Comment: I don't understand why you don't fetch it?